# Is the windows xp administrator account enabled by default

Tags: windows, windows-xp, administrator

I have dilemma with an old laptop with windows xp. I forgot my password but I'm told that you can login as the administrator (which I never messed with in any way when I had access), by pressing ctrl alt del at the welcome screen. But I also heard that it's not enabled by default, but that you can boot into safe mode and do it there. If I didn't disabled/enable it, or change the password, how can I get access to the administrator account?

Comment: Microsoft have published extensive documentation on how to recover lost password: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321305

Answer (score 1):

In order to enable the built-in Administrator account, you must be logged in as an administrative user.  First you must reset your account's password by doing one of the following:

1. Log into a different administrative user (if available) and change your password.
2. Use a Windows [Password Reset Disk](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305478) (if available).
3. Use a boot tool like [Offline Windows Password & Registry Editor](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) (which is included in [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd)) to reset your account's password.

The latter should only be done on a computer that you legally own.

---

Once you have access to an administrative account with the above method, you can enable the default Administrator account by doing one of the following:

1. Right-click My Computer, then click Manage.
2. Expand Local Users & Groups, then select Users
3. Right click the Administrator user and click Properties.
4. Enable the account and click Okay.

**Alternative method:**

1. Click Start, Run and type Regedit.exe
   Navigate to the following key:
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SOFTWARE \ Microsoft \ Windows NT \ CurrentVersion \ Winlogon \ SpecialAccounts \ UserList`
2. Use the File, Export option to backup the key
3. Create a new DWORD Value named Administrator
4. Double-click Administrator, and set 1 as its data
5. Exit the Registry Editor.

*In Windows XP Home Edition, you can unhide the Administrator account, but you cannot log into via normal login mode.*

Comment: Ophcrack would also be useful for seeing what the password is.  Almost no one has a 15 char or longer password.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows XP, the built-in administrator is disabled by default, and there is no password assigned to that account. You can only access the built-in administrator account from Safe Mode.

If you still can't log on to Windows, try the freeware [chntpw](http://www.chntpw.com/guide/) (also known as Offline NT Password & Registry Editor) program and it can reset (clear) the password.

Answer (score 0):

By default, yes.

I have, unfortunately been able to recover many-a-forgotten password by booting to safe mode, and logging into the Administrator account.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of methods to reset windows password which is not limited to Windows XP.

1. Reinstall Windows. However, data on C:\ will be deleted.
2. Create a Windows reset disk with USB drive and [reset password](http://www.uukeys.com/reset-windows-xp-password.html) with it. This is recommended. Simple and no data loss.
3. Use [Ubuntu Live CD](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14369/change-or-reset-windows-password-from-a-ubuntu-live-cd/) to reset the password.
4. If you sigh in with MS account, then you can change the password on web and log in with the new password.

Comment: The question isn't really about resetting a Windows password. Also, you should describe how to perform each of these to resolve the situation described in the original question.